# how to make round button for another method

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            GraphicsPath Gcircle = new GraphicsPath();
            Gcircle.AddEllipse(0, 0, 50, 50);
            this.button1.Region = new Region(Gcircle);
        }
```

I want to make a beautiful button,but button of above method is very ugly
there is another way to do ???

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/361271/3970411

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounded edges in button C# (WinForms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486521/rounded-edges-in-button-c-sharp-winforms)

Comment: Building a beautiful UI in Windows Forms is like building a romantic candlelight dinner from grey lego bricks. Won't happen. Look into WPF if you want some real beauty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this links if this is what your need
www.codeproject.com/Articles/5082/Round-Button-in-C

www.codeproject.com/Articles/5582/Elongated-Buttons-Rounded-cornered-Groupboxes-and

www.codeproject.com/Articles/15730/RoundButton-Windows-Control-Ever-Decreasing-Circle