# Problems with pictureboxs and transparency

Tags: c#

I'm trying to develop a poker replayer hands but I am facing a problem that does not really know how to solve. With the methods below:

```
public Replayer() //ctor
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pics = null;
        iCounter = 0;
        bShow = true;

        var pos = picTable.PointToScreen(picTable.Location);
        pos = picTable.PointToClient(pos);
        picTable.Parent = picBackground;
        picTable.Location = pos;
        picTable.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        TenPlayerHoldem(); // for only test   
    }

 private void TenPlayerHoldem() // only test
    {
        int iCounter = 10;

        pics = new PictureBox[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < iCounter; i++)
        {
            pics[i] = new PictureBox();
            pics[i].Name = "pics" + i.ToString();
            pics[i].Size = new Size(148, 74);
            pics[i].Image = FreePokerReplayer.Properties.Resources.seatbold;
            pics[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pics[i].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pics[i].Visible = true;
            pics[i].MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(pics_Click);
            picTable.Controls.Add(pics[i]);
        }

        pics[0].Location = new Point(379, 410);
        var pos00 = pics[0].PointToScreen(pics[0].Location);
        pos00 = pics[0].PointToClient(pos00);
        pics[0].Parent = picTable;
        pics[0].Location = pos00;

        pics[1].Location = new Point(188, 377);
        var pos01 = pics[1].PointToScreen(pics[1].Location);
        pos01 = pics[1].PointToClient(pos01);
        pics[1].Parent = picTable;
        pics[1].Location = pos01;

        pics[2].Location = new Point(56, 288);
        var pos02 = pics[2].PointToScreen(pics[2].Location);
        pos02 = pics[2].PointToClient(pos02);
        pics[2].Parent = picTable;
        pics[2].Location = pos02;
```

**I  got this result:**
[image]

So with the code:

```
//another picturebox    
var poscard = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(pictureBox1.Location);
poscard = pictureBox1.PointToClient(poscard);
pictureBox1.Parent = picTable;
pictureBox1.Location = poscard;
```

**Result is:**
[image]

the card is cut off ... I tried everything I knew to solve but no use. Any idea how to make the card appear behind the image, that is, part of the card be hidden without this "cut"?

Grateful for the help.

Comment: `pics[i].Size = new Size(148, 74);` Have you tried changing these values? They look wrong. For a playing card, the height should be like 2 or 3 times the width.

Comment: use `BringToFront()`

Comment: i would recommend you to first give us some runtime values like @JohnnyMopp said the size of the cards etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments all apply but since your title mentions transparency you ought to realize that there is strictly **no transparency** for **overlapping** controls.

Only **nested** controls can be transparent.

This seems to be the problem you have:

- It looks like the ovals are **nested** in the table, so their transparency works.
- But **the card and the oval are **overlapping**, so transparency between them does not work**.

You can workaround by making the the ovals **rounded rectangles** using a `region`..

See [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486521/rounded-edges-in-button-c-sharp-winforms/28486964?s=2|1.4945#28486964) but there are quite a few other code examples you find when searching for 'rounded rectangle'..

Since you need many of them best make a `RoundedPictureBox` class!

Usually the best solution is to not use any Controls for displaying (non-rectangluar) images but to `DrawImage` them.

Comment: Thank TaW actually rounding the rectangle the result is better, which is really killing me AddArc method are the coordinates for the perfect way an "oval rectangle"

Thankful again

Comment: Well, do not touch them, I'd say.. When calling the `GetRoundPath` function you just need to use half the height as the radius, no?

Comment: If you are happy with an answer, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!